# What does "they" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, antecedents

> WHEN A CRICKETER reaches 100 runs, they have the chance to reflect on what they have achieved, but also to take a “fresh guard” so they are ready for the challenges that await.

As we know "they" refers to a plural noun, but here "A Cricketer" is a singular noun.
What is the antecedent of "they" in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [singular *they*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). "They" can be used to refer to a singular person when the person's gender is not known or it is not desirable to attribute a gender to the person.